# Como ejecutar comandos del terminal con jquery y html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estoy haciendo una pagina web, quisiera que al hacer click en un boton en html mediante jquery se abra el terminal y ejecute una serie de comandos, en si lo que quiero es que al presionar el boton en html se abra el Writer (Estoy en linux), ya que debo dar instrucción sobre las herramientas ofimaticas, pero quiero hacerlo dinamico, si podrian ayudarme les agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Que yo sepa no puedes hacer algo así por razones de seguridad. En los navegadores de Microsoft eso se podría hacer mediante controles de ActiveX pero para otros lo desconozco.

Comment: Es posible que haya librerias que "emulen" una ventana terminal dentro de una web, pero es imposible dar acceso a tu terminal desde una pagina web. Quizas sea posible crear un backend con NodeJS y desde ahi acceder al sistema operativo, pero esto no podria abrir un terminal.

Comment: Otra opción es usar node y electron en una aplicación nativa.

Comment: y abra alguna otra manera de poder mandar a abrir el programa sin necesidad de ser por el terminal?